# rosbag::MessageInstance derefenced pointer error

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow this sample code to pull data from a bag file but am running into a bug that I cannot figure out. Hopefully this is the right forum to ask this in.

The c++ api specially "Example usage for read:" of the link below.
http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API

I successfully recreated the write/read bag file examples, but when trying to apply to my own problem I cannot access the data within the returned pointer of rosbag::MessageInstance.instantiate().

I have a bag file containing topic /robot_mode of type std_msgs::Int8 that I would like to access its data member. However the call to robot_mode_p->data returns strange items.

Sample code:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
{
    cout << m.getTopic() << endl;
    if (m.getTopic() == mode_topic )
    {
        std_msgs::Int8::ConstPtr robot_mode_p = m.instantiate<std_msgs::Int8>();
        std::string message_def = m.getDataType();
        cout << message_def << endl;
        cout << "robot_mode_p: " << *robot_mode_p << endl;
        if (robot_mode_p != nullptr)
            cout << "Dereferenced robot_mode: " << robot_mode_p->data << endl;
    }

}
```

I would expect in output of:

```
/robot_mode
std_msgs/Int8
robot_mode_p: data: 24

Dereferenced robot_mode: 24
```

But my code outputs:

```
/robot_mode
std_msgs/Int8
robot_mode_p: data: 24

Dereferenced robot_mode:
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

drive folder for bag file and sample code if interested:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Bj2MONuQREMg74W9DkJqABTe3bQRd3CV?usp=sharing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339749/rosbag::messageinstance-derefenced-pointer-error/) by [matthewlefort](https://answers.ros.org/users/27978/matthewlefort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wrap the value in a cast

```
cout << "Dereferenced robot_mode: " << static_cast<int>(robot_mode_p->data) << endl;
```

---

Originally posted by [EFernandes](https://answers.ros.org/users/13791/efernandes/) with karma: 51 on 2019-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matthewlefort](https://answers.ros.org/users/27978/matthewlefort/) on 2019-12-12**:
Wow! Thank you for the quick reply and correct answer. I will take a look at casting and pointers, would like to understand the why behind this.

For those interested:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/
seems the static_cast is returning the pointer to its base type (int)? Please correct me if I misunderstand.

**Comment by [EFernandes](https://answers.ros.org/users/13791/efernandes/) on 2019-12-12**:
Glad to help!
While I recommend to still look at casting and pointers, the problem it's not related to that, but cout itself.
If you tried to print robot_mode_p.data (no pointer) it would still not print correctly without the cast.